# Probability of consecutive occurrences of characters

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a text file like following.

```
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C
A,B,C,E
C,D,E
C,D,E,B,A
```

I need to find probability of consecutive occurrences of characters. In this case probability of B occurring after A

```
B occurring after A(A->B) = (No of time B occurring after A)/(No of times A occurs)
```

So the probability is

```
3/4 = 0.75
```

Like wise I need to calculate all pairwise probabilities.

```
A->B
B->A
A->C
C->A
A->D ...etc.
```

I cannot figure out how to start implementing this thing? Using a pandas `DataFrmae` is also fine. Any help on this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You know how to calculate it so show what code you tried and be specific about where it's going wrong

Comment: @EdChum : Can you please suggest how to find this consecutive occurrences? So I can implement the rest.

Comment: How are you interpreting consecutive here? Is this row-wise or column-wise, in your example you say A probability would be 3/4 but I don't see consecutive A's after B unless you mean column-wise but that would mean 2 not 3. Do you mean the count of A's after a particular instance of A after a specific letter (in this case B), that would make sense, if so please update your post

Comment: @EdChum: I have updated, B occuring after A, row wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brute force:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['A','B','C','D','E'],
        ['A','B','C'],
        ['A','B','C','E'],
        ['C','D','E'],
        ['C','D','E','B','A']]
characters = [i for j in data for i in j]
counts = {}
combinations = defaultdict(int)
for character in set(characters):
    counts[character] = characters.count(character)
    for character2 in set(characters):
        for entry in data:
            combination = [character, character2]
            if "".join(combination) in "".join(entry):
                combinations[tuple(combination)] += 1
probability = {i: combinations[i]/float(counts[i[0]]) for i in combinations}
probability

{('A', 'B'): 0.75,
  ('B', 'A'): 0.25,
  ('B', 'C'): 0.75,
  ('C', 'D'): 0.6,
  ('C', 'E'): 0.2,
  ('D', 'E'): 1.0,
  ('E', 'B'): 0.25}
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch Serbitar! This makes much sense.